# Apache tomcat server v8 fails to start in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am developing web application in Java using JSP and Servlet. But when I start my Apache tomcat server v8 it takes some time and after this it display message of `Server Tomcat v8 Server at localhost failed to start`

Comment: Console log ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Welcome, you should look at [ask]